# Need tutorials on developing the chromecast built-in device

Tags: google-cast

I'm looking for tutorials or developers guideline docs to develop the chromecast built-in devices. Actually, I want to know software structure and how to get required libraries or sample codes on chromecast built-in in a linux device with screen.

I've already looked at the google cast SDK documentation from https://developers.google.com/cast/. However, it contains content about application and streaming services. I have not found what I want yet.

for example,

- required DRM (widevine or playready)
- media pipeline integration
- device discovery (DIAL???)
- application lifecycle management (if needed)

I expect how I can get documentation and resources on what I need to understand for "google cast built-in device" development. Thank you.

Comment: The you should have been looking to some available resources in github for [Google Cast](https://github.com/googlecast/). This was also specified in the [Google Cast documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/tutorials) itself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But, I don't want to develop a receiver app, I want to port the CAST framework on embedded linux system. :-)